# rancid VIEWVC apache rewrite rule, CGI page incorrectly shown

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, viewvc

i configured rancid VIEWVC web page, CentOS 8

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www
        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin"
        ScriptAlias /viewvc /var/www/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi
        ScriptAlias /query /var/www/cgi-bin/query.cgi
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

It works fine when accessing `http://ip/viewvc`

I want to access to VIEWVC page by `http://ip`

so i modified conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www
        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin"
        ScriptAlias /viewvc /var/www/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi
        ScriptAlias /query /var/www/cgi-bin/query.cgi
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteRule (.*) /var/www/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride All
    Options +ExecCGI -Indexes
    AddHandler cgi-script cgi py
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

with redirection, page is "partially" loaded

http://IP

[image]

Without redirection all works fine

http:/ip/viewvc

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try at least `RewriteRule ^/$` instead otherwise any static assets will be rewritten to the CGI too.